# ESP8266 NodeMCU out of memory

Tags: memory-management, lua, out-of-memory, esp8266, nodemcu

NodeMCU info

```
> Lua 5.1.4 
> SDK 2.2.1
> Memory Usage :
> Total : 3260490 bytes 
> Used  : 9287 bytes 
> Remain: 3251203 bytes
```

Error I get when I try to send HTTP response with big json string response (`json_response`)

```
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (file.lua:5: out of memory)
```

Code:

```
  -- a simple HTTP server
    srv = net.createServer(net.TCP)
    srv:listen(80, function(conn)
        conn:on("receive", function(sck, payload)
            sck:send("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n"..json_response)
        end)
        conn:on("sent", function(sck) sck:close() end)
    end)
```

Comment: Any further feedback required here?

Comment: @MarcelStör I was seeing if there could be a way of adjusting the memory to handle it once, though I guess it's not possible yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that won't work if you're trying to send a lot of data. You need to send this piece-by-piece. [Our API documentation](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/net/#netsocketsend) shows two approaches (you would find further references here on SO) the first being this:

```
srv = net.createServer(net.TCP)

function receiver(sck, data)
  local response = {}

  -- if you're sending back HTML over HTTP you'll want something like this instead
  -- local response = {"HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nServer: NodeMCU on ESP8266\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n"}

  response[#response + 1] = "lots of data"
  response[#response + 1] = "even more data"
  response[#response + 1] = "e.g. content read from a file"

  -- sends and removes the first element from the 'response' table
  local function send(localSocket)
    if #response > 0 then
      localSocket:send(table.remove(response, 1))
    else
      localSocket:close()
      response = nil
    end
  end

  -- triggers the send() function again once the first chunk of data was sent
  sck:on("sent", send)

  send(sck)
end

srv:listen(80, function(conn)
  conn:on("receive", receiver)
end)
```